# Double integral over a typical region.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> **Question**: Let $R$ be the region in $xy$-plane bounded by the curves $y=x^2,y=4x^2,xy=1,xy=5$.
> Then find the value of line integral $\iint_R\frac{y^2}{x}dydx$.

I found it tough and time taking if I evaluate this integral from general method, is there any theorem which make it easy? Since the question is asked in competitive exam so I hope there must be an easy and fast way to solve it.

Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "general method"? Please show what you tried.

Comment: @Robert by general method I mean the usual approach we do to solve double integral

Comment: If I go through what I have been taught in class then it would be very difficult task and and time taking too

Comment: Have you calculated the intersections of the assigned curves to understand where the $x$ and $y$ varie?

Comment: Yes I have drawn region,but the problem I am facing is that between two limits upper and lower curves are changing

Comment: Do you know how to do change of variable? That would be the simplest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest change of variable as -

$\displaystyle xy = u, \frac{y}{x^2} = v$

That leads to $\displaystyle J = \frac{1}{3v}$ and integrand $\displaystyle \frac{y^2}{x} = uv$

So the integral simplifies to $\displaystyle \int_1^4 \int_1^5 \frac{u}{3} du \, dv = 12$

The intuition for change of variable comes from seeing the curves they are bound by. As you have two curves with $xy = c$ and two curves with $y = cx^2$. So you can use change of variable to integrate over a rectangular region. One of them is $u = xy$ and the other can be $\frac{x^2}{y}$ or $\frac{y}{x^2}$. I chose the latter as it simplified the integrand as $\frac{y^2}{x} = uv$.

Comment: thank you so much,It helps a lot.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Try a [change of variables](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChangeofVariablesTheorem.html) by letting $u=x^2/y$ and $v=xy$. Then the region $R$  is transformed into the rectangle $[1/4,1]\times [1,5]$. Since the [Jacobian determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Jacobian_determinant) is
$$\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}& \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}\right)
=\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}
2x/y& -x^2/y^2\\
y& x
\end{bmatrix}\right)=\frac{3x^2}{y},$$
it follows that
$$\iint_R\frac{y^2}{x}dydx=\frac{1}{3}\int_{u=1/4}^1\int_{v=1}^5\frac{y^3}{x^3}dvdu=
\frac{1}{3}\int_{1/4}^1\frac{du}{u^2}\cdot\int_{1}^5vdv.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Ibs Have you a numerical result?

Comment: @Ribertz the answer is 12

Comment: Then, if you follow my advice you will find the correct answer.

Comment: I understand your approach but the main the main problem is how to think of such a variable change?

Comment: It's the change of variables which transforms your region into a rectangle.

Comment: thanks I understood now

Comment: why you take inverse of Jacobian in integral,same thing confusing me Mathlover's answer,if you calculate determinant of Jacobian provided by you in link then I am not getting the value which you use after inverting the value of determinant of Jacobian found by you....please elaborate it

Comment: @Ibs Note that that if $J$ is the given jacobian, then $|J|dxdy=dudv$.

Comment: is it true that $\left|\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}\right|=\left|\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)}\right|^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Inverse

Comment: $\left|\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}\right|=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{pmatrix}$,right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct!

Comment: And then $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}= \frac{1}   {\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}} ,\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}=\frac{1}{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x } }$ and so on,right?

Comment: Is the above step correct?,I think I am going wrong here since if I calculate Jacobian from here then it's not same as yours which is correct.

Comment: have you got my point?

Comment: I don't understand your computations. Maybe you should ask another question on your doubts about the Jacobian showing the details of your work.